# About the google.golang.org/protobuf why use append not make a had cap slice

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

```
// AppendVarint appends v to b as a varint-encoded uint64.
func AppendVarint(b []byte, v uint64) []byte {
    switch {
    case v < 1<<7:
        b = append(b, byte(v))
    case v < 1<<14:
        b = append(b,
            byte((v>>0)&0x7f|0x80),
    
    // ...
    }
    return b
}
```

use append while need mem copy

but we had known the length

is this something better?

why not we do like this

```
switch {
    case v < 1<<7:
        b = []byte{byte(v)}
    case v < 1<<14:
        b = []byte{byte((v>>0)&0x7f|0x80), byte(v>>7)}
```

Comment: Can you please try to phrase your question more comprehensive and please explain what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

`append` appends to an existing slice, only reallocating “[[i]f the capacity  is not large enough to fit the additional values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)”. A slice literal always returns a unique (newly-allocated) slice.

Which one you use, in general, depends on what you're doing with it, but in the case of `protobuf` “what you're doing with it” is generally appending a varint-encoded integer to a (potentially much larger) serialized protocol message. In that case, `append` has the right semantics, while returning a new slice would potentially perform an unnecessary allocation (since that slice would itself just be appended onto the buffer containing the serialized message).